# Caddy always tries to bind to port 80, regardless of the address in Caddyfile

Tags: caddy

Caddy v2.2.1 doesn't seem to respect the port of a given address in this `Caddyfile`:

```
myfinedomain.com:9999 {
    respond "Nothing to see here. Srsly."
}
```

Starting up caddy simply results in the following error (taken from the log):

```json
{"level":"info","ts":1614777947.500496,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
{"level":"info","ts":1614777947.5004952,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc0002d2380"}
run: loading initial config: loading new config: http app module: start: tcp: listening on :80: listen tcp :80: bind: address already in use
start: caddy process exited with error: exit status 1
{"level":"info","ts":1614778157.9187949,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/usr/local/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
{"level":"info","ts":1614778157.9210048,"logger":"admin","msg":"admin endpoint started","address":"tcp/localhost:2019","enforce_origin":false,"origins":["[::1]:2019","127.0.0.1:2019","localhost:2019"]}
{"level":"info","ts":1614778157.9213488,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
{"level":"info","ts":1614778157.92195,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc0002be3f0"}
run: loading initial config: loading new config: http app module: start: tcp: listening on :80: listen tcp :80: bind: address already in use
start: caddy process exited with error: exit status 1
```

Thus, caddy seems to try binding to port 80, which it shouldn't do.

The [documentation](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/concepts#addresses) lists the port as being a valid option for addresses.

Ideas on what might be missing here are appreciated.

Comment: What else is in the Caddyfile?

Comment: Nothing. That‘s the complete Caddyfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the clue that leads to explaining what is going on:

```
{"level":"info","ts":1614778157.9213488,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
```

Looking this up gives the explanation that Caddy [*automatically*](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https) attempts to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and manage TLS certificates except in various circumstances, such as the user [explicitly disabling](https://caddyserver.com/docs/json/apps/http/servers/automatic_https/) the functionality.

If you do not intend to run an HTTPS web site, you should explicitly disable this functionality, or consider using a different web server.

Comment: Thanks. The automatic HTTPS handling is indeed a feature and actually the reason for me to eventually switch to Caddy. However, at first I need to transfer all the server's domain's configs over to caddy. For this, I use those non-standard port numbers. 

Is there an option to (temporarily) disable HTTPS in some Caddyfile?

Comment: Nevermind, prefixing the domain with the `http` scheme does exactly that.

Comment: Disabling https redirects using a caddy file: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/options#auto-https `{ auto_https disable_redirects }`. Add new lines after `{` and before `}`